# White space between frame and dialogue box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using xaml and trying to figure out how to fix the frame error. I see the dialogue box is not fitted exactly to window frame. Please take a look at following link.

Code as follows:

```
Full Code: <Page x:Class="ccf_envcheck.Pages.HomePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ccf_envcheck"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="380"
  Title="HomePage" Width="340.976" >
      <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text = ". . . " Height="50" Width="300" Margin = "10" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
           <TextBlock Text = ". . . " Height="50" Width="300" Margin = "0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
           <Button Click="FirstDevice" Content="First Device" Margin="10,15,14,1"/>
           <Button Click="SecondDevice" Content="Second Device" Margin="10,15,14,1"/>
      </StackPanel>
  </Page>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add full code ?

Comment: Code posted @CodeNoob

Answer (score 0):

If you see your code in the Page initalizing attributes you have hardcoded the width to 340.986 and I think that is the reason why the Frame and Dialogue box don't have same width. Can you try removing it and check if it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried building code without the "Width" parameter, I still have the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried running the code. Works fine on my machine. Can you check if there is no margin set from code behind? Apart from that I dont see any issue in this code.

Comment: Okay. I shall look in to it. Thanks though.